# pip cannot install arbitrary modules

Tags: python, pip

for every deploy to our test servers we install a number of packages using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
```

In probably half the cases pip fails to install a package returning an error such as

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-brotli==0.1.3 (from -r configuration/environments/dev/../requirements.txt (line 66)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django-brotli==0.1.3 (from -r configuration/environments/dev/../requirements.txt (line 66))
```

Two observations:

- The packages pip cannot install do exist - the installation worked fine in previous and in later builds.
- The package that fails is arbitrary

We're running multiple builds in parallel in different venvs, so I assume it's sort of a race condition.
I've already made sure that the environment variable **TMPDIR** is set to a different location for each of the build processes but the problem still exists.

Any idea where else the pip processes could interfere which each other?

I'm using pip 18.1 with python 3.5.3

Comment: Your version of both pip and python might be important here!

Comment: Can you add `-vvv` to the `pip command` and add the output to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hoefling the additional verbose messages seemed to indicate that the problem was the caching that pip does, even though I wasn't really able to work out what the exact problem is.
It just looked like in some cases pip tried to find the version in the cache and just couldn't while a parallel process was able to find it.

Since I added the option `pip --no-cache` the problem didn't reoccur.